# How can I get already installed app bundle ID from my iPad. The app is not in App store yet

Tags: ios, local-storage, bundle-identifier

My App certificate is expired and I didn't have access to this certificate any more. I need to know bundle id of my app to create new version with that **bundle id** and new certificate to save **local db** from old app.

The app doesn't launching anymore and I have very important data in this app db and I want to save it. I have created many versions of this app and every time I have changed bundle id and I don't know which one is it.

I have tried iExplorer application, but it shows all apps bundle id except that app. Also I have crashlytics in that app, but it doesn't show crash.

If there is no way to know bundle id :(, may be there is the way to know the *installation date* of this app?

Comment: Can you connect your iPad to your mac device?

Comment: **NO** iPad is not with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i do understand your question right, you can try:

*Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> **INSTALLED APPS***

You can see there your apps on this device, and **name, version and identifier**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: iPad is not with me. The person who has it doesn't have Xcode